# How to calculate file upload progress in jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-file-upload

I have difficulties in understanding the `progress-bar` functionality of the `jquery-file-upload`.

What is meant by the following snippet?

```
.on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
        });
```

The questions are:

1. **How is the progress calculated**? Actually, the file name is passed to my `upload` controller and I save it immediately. Then how is this progress reported or by whom?
2. What is meant by the line, `parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);`

The original link to [Jquery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

Answer (score 1):

I think the script calculates the number of bytes which have been transported to from the client-side to the server.

The event **fileupload progressall** combines the information about all loading files and displays it at two variables `data.loaded`, and `data.total`.

`data.loaded` - how many bytes were loaded

`data.total`  - total size transferring data to server

`parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);` //will return the percent of uploaded data

About function [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `progressall` callback, but `data.total` could be inaccurate.

See here for a solution:

[jquery fileupload inaccurare progressbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593392/jquery-file-upload-progress-bar-inaccurate/52255627#52255627)